# Is the universal cover of an integral homology sphere again an integral homology sphere?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, homology-sphere

Let $\Sigma$ be an integral homology sphere (from now on I will drop the word 'integral').

If $\Sigma$ is simply connected, then it is homotopy equivalent to a sphere by Whitehead's Theorem, and hence homeomorphic to a sphere by the solution of the topological Poincaré conjecture.

If $\pi_1(\Sigma)$ is infinite, then $\widetilde{\Sigma}$ is non-compact; in particular, it is not a homology sphere.

Suppose now that $\pi_1(\Sigma)$ is finite but non-trivial. If $\dim\Sigma$ is even, then $\chi(\widetilde{\Sigma}) = |\pi_1(\Sigma)|\chi(\Sigma) = 2|\pi_1(\Sigma)|$, so $\widetilde{\Sigma}$ is not a homology sphere. If $\dim\Sigma$ is odd, then there are examples where $\widetilde{\Sigma}$ is a homology sphere, e.g. the [Poincaré homology sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere#Poincar.C3.A9_homology_sphere) which has $S^3$ as its universal cover.

> If $\Sigma$ is an odd-dimensional homology sphere and $\pi_1(\Sigma)$ is finite, is $\widetilde{\Sigma}$ necessarily a homology sphere?

If the answer were yes, then $\widetilde{\Sigma}$ would be a simply connected homology sphere and hence $\widetilde{\Sigma}$ is a sphere by the argument above. In dimension three, the only homology sphere with finite fundamental group is the Poincaré homology sphere, so if there is a counterexample (which I suspect there is), it must have dimension at least five.

Comment: A simply connected homology sphere is $S^n$, so you're essentially asking about group actions on $S^n$. You can approach this via the classification which shows that the Poincare sphere is special. I was thinking about it the other day but I don't have a simple proof that it's the only integer homology sphere spherical space form.

Comment: (In fact, you can use Kervaire to build 5-manifolds which are homology spheres with specified fundamental group whose first and second homology vanishes. There are many of these that don't act freely on a sphere.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be concrete, take any finite simple noncyclic group with trivial Schur multiplier, e.g. $G=A_2(9)$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups) for more examples). Then, by [Kervaire's theorem](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-144-00/S0002-9947-1969-0253347-3/S0002-9947-1969-0253347-3.pdf), for every $k\ge 5$ there exists a $k$-dimensional integer homology sphere $M$ with $\pi_1(M)=G$. Milnor proved (see [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372566?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)) that if $G$ is a finite group acting freely on a sphere then every involution in $G$ has to be central. All finite noncyclic simple groups contain involutions; by simplicity, such involutions cannot be central. It follows that the universal cover of $M$ cannot be a homology sphere.

Edit. An explicit example of an involution in $A_2(n)=PSL(3, {\mathrm F}_n)$ is given by the projectitization of the matrix
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-1&0&0\\
0&-1&0\\
0&0&1\end{array}\right]. 
$$
One can also see, by inspection, that all simple noncyclic groups of Lie type contain involutions, equivalently, have even order. It is a deep theorem of Feit and Thompson ([odd order theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit%E2%80%93Thompson_theorem)) that every finite group of odd order is solvable. In other words, every non-solvable finite group contains an involution.

Comment: Why do such groups contain involutions?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Every finite simple noncyclic group contains involutions. This is actually a very deep theorem, part of the classification of finite simple groups. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit%E2%80%93Thompson_theorem

Comment: $PSL(2,9)\cong A_6$ has Schur multiplier of order $6$.

Comment: @Hempelicious: You are right, it is $A_2(9)\cong PSL(3,9)$.